# Does realloc(p, 0) really involves free(p) in glibc?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, glibc

I found that some people and references like books state that if `p != NULL` and `p` origins from previous allocation (e.g. by `malloc`), then `realloc(p, 0)` is equivalent to `free(p)` on GNU/Linux. To support this thesis [`man realloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) states exactly in that manner (emphasis mine going forward):

> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to
>   by ptr to size bytes. The contents will be unchanged in the range from
>   the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes. If
>   the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be
>   initialized. If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to
>   malloc(size), for all values of size; **if size is equal to zero, and
>   ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr)**. Unless ptr
>   is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(),
>   calloc() or realloc(). If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr)
>   is done.

As you may find in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759849/using-realloc-x-0-instead-of-free-and-using-malloc-with-length-of-a-string), the C Standard does not define precisely what should happen and actual behavior is implementation-defined. More specifically:

The C11 §7.22.3/p1 *Memory management functions* says:

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: **either a null pointer is returned**, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

and C11 §7.22.3.5 *The realloc function* contains:

> 3) (...) If memory for the new object **cannot be allocated**, the old
>   object **is not deallocated** and its **value is unchanged**.
>
> 4) The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may
>   have the same value as a pointer to the old object), **or a null pointer
>   if the new object could not be allocated**.

I wrote some basic code to find out actual behavior with help of [`mcheck`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html), memory checker, that is supplied with `glibc`:

```
#include <mcheck.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int *p, *q;

    mtrace();

    p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    q = &a;

    printf("%p\n", (void *) p);
    printf("%p\n", (void *) q);

    q = realloc(p, 0);

    printf("%p\n", (void *) p);
    printf("%p\n", (void *) q);

    return 0;
}
```

and results are:

```
$ gcc -g check.c 
$ export MALLOC_TRACE=report
$ ./a.out 
0xfd3460
0x7ffffbc955cc
0xfd3460
(nil)
[grzegorz@centos workspace]$ mtrace a.out report 

Memory not freed:
-----------------
           Address     Size     Caller
0x0000000000fd3460      0x4  at /home/grzegorz/workspace/check.c:12
```

As you may see `q` was set to `NULL`. It seems that `free()` was not really called. In fact it can't be unless my interpretation is incorrect: since `realloc` has returned `NULL` pointer, the new object could not have been allocated, which implies that:

> the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged

Is this correct?

Comment: The wording about `realloc(ptr, 0)` being equivalent to `free(ptr)` used to be in POSIX, but the [official POSIX `realloc` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) now uses the language from the C standard. The POSIX standard does however say "if `realloc()` returns a null pointer, the space pointed to by p has not been freed".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: Your glibc seems to be a pre-2.18, in 2.18 a bug was fixed in mtrace (see [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14981)). On a 2.20 glibc your test program reports: "No memory leaks."

`free` is called in glibc. From the sources of current glibc 2.21 ([here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c#l376) and [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c#l2966)):

```
/*
  REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES should be set if a call to
  realloc with zero bytes should be the same as a call to free.
  This is required by the C standard. Otherwise, since this malloc
  returns a unique pointer for malloc(0), so does realloc(p, 0).
*/

#ifndef REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES
#define REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES 1
#endif

void *
__libc_realloc (void *oldmem, size_t bytes)
{
  mstate ar_ptr;
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T nb;         /* padded request size */

  void *newp;             /* chunk to return */

  void *(*hook) (void *, size_t, const void *) =
    atomic_forced_read (__realloc_hook);
  if (__builtin_expect (hook != NULL, 0))
    return (*hook)(oldmem, bytes, RETURN_ADDRESS (0));

#if REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES
  if (bytes == 0 && oldmem != NULL)
    {
      __libc_free (oldmem); return 0;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: This doesn't rule out some header (perhaps optionally) defining `REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES` as zero. No header is doing so, but I think you should mention that in your answer.

Comment: @hvd Defining `REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES` only has an effect when you are *building* glibc. It has no effect when you are only using the library.

Comment: @一二三 Well duh. :) I'm referring to the headers that glibc is using itself. This isn't the complete source file. The complete source file contains `#include` directives.

Answer (score 7):

Though my intepretation of "returned `NULL`" case seems to be correct (see my edit below), `glibc` developers [decided](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12547) to keep it consistent with previous C89 Standard and rejected to conform with C99/C11:

> There is no way this will be changed.  This is how it has been
>   implemented forever.  C should document existing practice.  Changing
>   it would mean introducing memory leaks.

Also `mcheck` indication was misleading, as other test-case has showed that memory *is* effectively freed by `realloc`:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p, *q;

    p = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
    malloc_stats();

    putchar('\n');

    q = realloc(p, 0);
    malloc_stats();

    return 0;
}
```

Here, output is:

```
$ gcc check.c 
$ ./a.out 
Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =         96
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =         96
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0

Arena 0:
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =          0
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =     135168
in use bytes     =          0
max mmap regions =          0
max mmap bytes   =          0
```

**EDIT:**

As hvd pointed in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659940/does-reallocp-0-really-involves-freep-in-glibc#comment45621700_28662843), the ISO/IEC Working Group had some discussion, materialized as [Defect Report #400](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/dr_400.htm). The proposed changes may likely allow existing practice of `glibc` in the future revision of the C Standard (or possibly as Technical Corrigendum 1 for C11).

What I *really* like about DR #400 is proposition to:

> Add to subsection 7.31.12 a new paragraph (paragraph 2):
>
> Invoking realloc with a size argument equal to zero is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: +1 for citing the bug tracker. I've re-opened the issue since the decision was made by glibc's former dictator who's now moved on.

Comment: @R.. Is there any glibc bug, though? C changed to re-allow the C90 and glibc behaviour if I'm reading [DR #400](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/dr_400.htm) correctly. Or was that never accepted?

Comment: @hvd: I suppose that will be in the next TC to C11, so maybe that's enough to make people happy. I still think it's confusing though. The first change made in the proposed TC for the DR makes it sound like NULL is only a valid return value for `realloc` when an error occurred.

Comment: @R.. That is exactly what it means, and that's also what C99 intended. That part is a just a clarification. When `realloc` returns `NULL`, that does indicate a failure to allocate memory. However, in the past, failure to allocate memory would guarantee the previously-allocated memory would remain available. It's that last guarantee that's changed: if `size` is `0`, that's no longer guaranteed.

Comment: Would there be any problem with allowing `malloc`-style functions to process a zero-byte allocation request by returning the address of a static dummy object, provided that `realloc` and `free` interpret treat such an address as equivalent to a null pointer?  That would allow an implementation to guarantee that `realloc(ptr,0)` will never return null and yet also allow user code to ignore its return value without creating memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

As the behaviour of `realloc()` when being passed a size of 0 is implenentation defined ...

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, ***or*** the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

... the portable equivalent to

```
void * p = malloc(1);
free(p);
```

needs to be

```
void * p = malloc(1);
p = realloc(p, 0)
free(p); /* because of the part after the "or" as quoted above.
```

The memory balance should be even afterwards.

Update covering `realloc()`'s "error" case:

```
void * p = malloc(1);
{
  void * q = realloc(p, 0);
  p = q ?q :p;
}
free(p); /* because of the part after the "or" as quoted above.
```

Comment: If `realloc` returns a NULL pointer, you've lost the pointer that needs to be freed :(

Comment: You mean the portable equivalent to `void *p = malloc(1); realloc(p, 0);` right?

Comment: @BenVoigt if `realloc` returns a NULL pointer, you don't know whether to free the old pointer or not!

Comment: @immibis: Indeed. This is why implementations like glibc's are utterly broken, and why application code should refrain from ever passing a size of 0 to `realloc`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE The fault is not glibc but the C89 that was different and explicit requested this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `realloc` code in `glibc` here : http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/memusage.c.html#realloc. You will see at line 434 that `free` is called when size is 0.

Comment: Are you sure this is *the* implementation of glibc's `realloc`? I find the sources quite confusing, and this source file contains the comment (in the first line) "Profile heap and stack memory usage of running program." There is another file, `malloc/malloc.c`, which contains `__libc_realloc`, which is aliased to `realloc`. That implementation in fact contains a compiler switch called `REALLOC_ZERO_BYTES_FREES` that influences the behaviour in this case.

Comment: You are right. In http://osxr.org/glibc/source/malloc/malloc.c see lines 571--574. Don't know when this is set or not...

Comment: Also see lines 217--220 in http://www.atnf.csiro.au/computing/software/casacore/casacore-1.2.0/doc/html/malloc_8h_source.html. Defining this symbols is a matter of consistency with `malloc` behavior on zero size allocations.