# Can we free dynamically allocation memory using realloc?

Tags: c, heap-memory

My friend and I had a discussion over freeing dynamically allocated memory. He told that a memory could be freed with realloc(), to which I denied.
Let's consider the below code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    int *q = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

    free(p);
    p = NULL;

    realloc(q, sizeof(int) * 0);
    q = NULL;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Let's assume **p** and **q** are pointing to address `0x1000` & `0x2000` respectively.
In the above code, **p** and **q** are `int` pointers pointing to dynamically allocated 40 bytes of memory blocks in the RAM. On executing `free(p)` frees the memory address (`0x1000`). The freed memory address (`0x1000`) could be used by an OS again. Then, **NULL** is assigned to pointer variable `p` to prevent `p` of becoming a dangling pointer.

```
realloc(q, sizeof(int) * 0);
```

`realloc()` simply shrinks the memory block pointed by **q** to zero. But **q** still points to the same address (`0x2000`), and that address is not freed. On assigning NULL value to pointer **q**, **q** now points to NULL and the address (`0x2000`) to which **q** was pointing is not freed and the link to that address (`0x2000`) is lost. That address (`0x2000`) cannot be used by OS in the future until the end of the program.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What evidence do you have that what q points to has not been freed?

Comment: Even if the second parameter to `realloc()` is 0, the entry in the data structure in the heap, that the memory allocation functions use is not free'd (not returned to the available memory pool),  use the functions as they were designed to be used.

Comment: yes, your understanding is correct, with one caveat.  usually when a memory allocation is shrunk, the actual memory reserved is not shrank

Comment: "realloc() simply shrinks the memory block pointed by q to zero." --> maybe, maybe not.  C does not specify that `realloc()` _must_ operate in that manner.  That is one one many possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

```
realloc(q, sizeof(int) * 0);
```

is same as

```
realloc(q, 0);
```

The C standard in *7.22.3.5 ->2 The realloc function* says :

> ..and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by
>   size. The contents of the new object shall be the same as that of the
>   old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of the new and old
>   sizes.

But it doesn't explicitly specify what would happen if the new size is zero. 
But you still have an `artist` pointer that could be passed to `free`.

Consider

```
char *a;
a=malloc(2*sizeof *a);
a=realloc(a,0);
// Note I'm purposely NOT using a temporary variable to store 'realloc' results
// Moreover, above is BAD practice.
free(a); // Is this permitted? YES !! Did we technically free memory above? NO !!
//Compiler will not yell at you for the above, in fact it is legal as per the standard
return 0; // No output for this one
```

vs

```
char *a;
a=malloc(2*sizeof *a);
free(a);
//You're not suppose to free(a) again.
free(a); 
//Compiler will yell at you for the above.
return 0;
```

**output**

```
double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000915010
```

---

**Conclusions**

- `deallocation` and `freeing` are not exactly the same things.
- Both `realloc` and `free` can deallocate memory, but only `free` frees the memory.

  ---

That said

```
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

is the recommended way to free memory. Do check [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025604/1620779) answer.

Answer (score 4):

`realloc(, 0)` is [implementation dependent and not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759849/using-realloc-x-0-instead-of-free-and-using-malloc-with-length-of-a-string) to `free()`.

That said, you *might* be lucky:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
        char *a;
        a = malloc(1024);
        printf("a = %08lx\n", a);
        free(a);
        a = malloc(1024);
        printf("a = %08lx\n", a);
        realloc(a, 0);
        a = malloc(1024);
        printf("a = %08lx\n", a);
}

gcc version 6.1.1 20160815 [gcc-6-branch revision 239479] (SUSE Linux)
ldd --version

ldd (GNU libc) 2.23

a = 01dad010
a = 01dad010
a = 01dad010
```

So the second malloc, after realloc(, 0), "sees" a free block where before was a. I take it to mean that **in this instance**, `realloc` duplicates the behaviour of `free`. **DO NOT RELY ON THIS**.